# Show that there is such a number as $\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}$.

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show such a thing?

This question is from a chapter on the archimedean postulate, but I can't seem to make the connection, or with any of the previous material for that matter.

Comment: What is the "previous material"?

Comment: If $x$ is a real number and $x > 0$, then there is a real number $\sqrt x$ such that $\sqrt x > 0$ and $(\sqrt x)^2 = x$. Have you proved (or seen a proof of) that yet?

Comment: By "Show that there is such a number...", I'm unclear on what the endgame is. Do i square it and square it again to get $3 + \sqrt2$? but How does that prove that there is such a number?

Comment: Oh right, so it would go along the lines of $2 \in \mathbb{R^+} \implies \sqrt2 > 0, \text{ also}  1+ \sqrt2 > 0 \implies \sqrt{1+ \sqrt2} > 0 $? Sorry for the stupidity, I have seen and proved that before, just the wording of the question left me hanging.

Answer (score 3):

Using the axioms of $\mathbb R$ (ordered field where each bounded set has a supremum) you can show that there is a square root function $s:\mathbb R^+_0\to \mathbb R^+_0$. So you want from $s$ that it satisfies $s(x)^2=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^+_0$. With that condition it is uniquely determined.

To see that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ exists, you only have to verify that $2\ge 0$ and $1+\sqrt{2}\ge 0$ which is an easy exercise using the axioms of $\mathbb R$. Here $\sqrt{x}:=s(x)$.